# cast data received from backend to a frontend interface in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, casting

I have data received from backend as following:

```
  id: number;
  user_id: number;
  car_brand: string;
  car_model: string;
  vin: string;
  equipment: string;
  reg_number: string;
  car_mileage: number;
  car_year: string;
```

and i have an interface in frontend as following:
UserCarType

```
  id: number;
  user_id: number;
  brand: string;
  model: string;
  vin: string;
  restyling:string
  govtNumber: string;
  mileage: number;
  year: string;
```

as you can observe the two types are identique but only preoprty names differ, how can i cast type received from backend to the frontent interface ?

I tried to use "as" keyword but without success, still preoperties with backend names.
I have found some sources where they talking about mapping and to create a fucntion that maps every function, please someone an provide me with best and effective solution ?

I also tried this:

```
  const car = {
    id: props.userCar.id,
    user_id: props.userCar.user_id,
    user_guid: props.userCar.user_guid,
    car_guid: props.userCar.car_guid,
    color_guid: props.userCar.color_guid,
    brand_guid: props.userCar.brand_guid,
    model_guid: props.userCar.model_guid,
    brand: props.userCar.car_brand,
    model: props.userCar.car_model,
    vin: props.userCar.vin,
    equipment: props.userCar.equip,
    govtNumber: props.userCar.reg_num,
    mileage: props.userCar.mileage,
    year: props.userCar.manuf_date,
    predictedPrice: props.userCar.sale_price,
    brandImage: props.userCar.logo,
    carImage: '', // Set the carImage property based on your data}
  };
```

but i would to know if there is a way to do it properly in typescript

Comment: Please make an attempt at creating your own solution and post your code here.

Comment: i'm asking for the solution, itried "as" keyword. I don't even know if we can do that, so i'm asking.

Comment: The `as` keyword will not help you here, and I'd not recommend to use it due to it will just typescript ignore all the possible errors with types. If you did a manual mapping and still seeing "server properties" - then the issue is somewhere else. As for me - the best solution is to create a directory with mappings that will map DTO models (data you are getting from server) to your actual models (i.e. `export function mapUserCarType(input: UserCarTypeDTO): UserCarType {.....}` and thats it.

Comment: ```  const propertyMapping = {
    car_brand: 'brand',
    car_model: 'model',
    equip: 'equipment',
    reg_num: 'govtNumber',
    manuf_date: 'year',
    sale_price: 'predictedPrice',
    logo: 'brandImage',
  };
  const car = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(props.userCar).map(([key, value]) => [
      propertyMapping[key] || key,
      value,
    ]),
  ); ```what do you think about this approach ?

Comment: You have to implement a solution yourself and there's no single "proper" way to do so in Typescript, nor is there a magic automatic way of doing so in the type system (which has no runtime effects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some other languages offer runtime **value** "casting", but TypeScript can't do that because [it only exists at compile time](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#typescript-a-static-type-checker) (not runtime). The only "casting" in TypeScript is simply making compile-time [**type** assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (compiler overrides), and this has no effect on runtime program data (just types).

If you're going to be copying values from an input object to a new object, but you want to copy the values to potentially different keys than the original: you might want a function to help with that task so that all you need to do is specify the mapping of input property names to output property names. Below is an example of such a function that you can modify to suit your needs:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSATA0hEBnAPAKClABQCcB7SI0eMKCAD2AgDskMoAlCOJExgGxCwcAxiSJIsGYEQCWjAOYAaKJJnyAfGoV4oASUZgArsBr0mLdp258Bw0eIDW6EgDNCpcpQRK4jEBq1qUAC8UADeUAC0RJY8-FAA2ihQslCOIC5uZBAUIFRQcKzEWTlUiQC6ZQBcuvpG5VAAvgDcODjOBoxCwNI8UAC2CGiYuPgijJKZHrkIJgzMrBxcsTYQImISUrKKypvqmtp6hsZ0c+aLVvyCq3ZYaRlFU1Tevv44agAUYO7ZnmDVDz9pmAlLIjtVDkYAJTVKjIIbYAElLw1I6BULaMYTaIYAy8YwhUINfKsWEQVDoBHfJHAlFGNQtfAAekZUAAAsAMBE6JAulyiKQiNpnKIoO9McY0slGFAvsVfpCoNjccB4rLHgh4mkKsEpUdNegygzFRBgAYiNKlXiWg1WqBIFAAMrZABu2QAwnAiDr0fhpEhqowDH0AEbZI0GDDZAD6foDQdDRCNQk9UeDRB8-p2qjkRuZUEAZAQmoQAOhwzVa4uULvdnuqTqIrqIHq9BO0sagAEYAAwdrT4CPR9sAVgALABmABMfagyaIqfTzGqACIAIJGEhu0RgJfTvOF4AlsstHB26Bu3jSJjAZvetuZwMhsPaAdz9sPhNGtMZ6oqLa5ln7oe5Y4JWQgXlezbVOel6MNeno6gMYDwu8PrJJmS5+juz6Rq+6EvjGSBYaMKZfouUBLqRhG7gBRalg0Sg4Y2zaQsemIkLwEDFrwJByGK4GwcxTRQMyQRomh1Tdr2UD4cO45TlAlHLmuwAbluS6NDgQA)

```ts
type MappedKeys<
  PropertyMap extends Readonly<Record<string, string>>,
  Input extends Readonly<Record<keyof PropertyMap, any>>,
> = { -readonly [K in keyof PropertyMap as PropertyMap[K]]: Input[K] };

function mapKeys<
  const PropertyMap extends Readonly<Record<string, string>>,
  Input extends Readonly<Record<keyof PropertyMap, any>>,
>(propertyMap: PropertyMap, input: Input): MappedKeys<PropertyMap, Input> {
  const result = {} as MappedKeys<PropertyMap, Input>;
  // @ts-expect-error
  for (const key in propertyMap) result[propertyMap[key]] = input[key];
  return result;
}

type ServerCar = {
  id: number;
  user_id: number;
  car_brand: string;
  // …etc.
};

const serverCar: ServerCar = {
  id: 101,
  user_id: 5432,
  car_brand: "AutoCorp",
  // …etc.
};

type ClientCar = {
  id: number;
  user_id: number;
  brand: string;
  // …etc.
};

const clientCar: ClientCar = mapKeys({
  id: "id",
  user_id: "user_id",
  car_brand: "brand",
  // …etc.
}, serverCar);

console.log(clientCar); //=> { id: 101, user_id: 5432, brand: "AutoCorp" }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **reinforcing what @Sergey Sosunov has told**, there's no direct TypeScript syntax for this property mapping task. The `as` keyword isn't suitable as it is for type assertions. In other words, it considers the object as another type than the type the compiler infers the object to be.

Furthermore, decoupling the mapping logic from the backend as you did is advantageous, as it isolates your code from potential backend changes and by the way ensures a more resilient application structure.

As @Sergey pointed out, using DTO services can serve as a practical solution ensuring consistent and accurate data transfer.