# Can I create a map of key-value pairs by deserializing from JSON?

Tags: javascript, typescript, performance, json-deserialization

I'm trying to create a `Map<TKey, TValue>` instance by deserializing a JSON document, but what I'm actually getting seems to be a different type of object, with none of the methods that `Map<TKey, TValue>` has.

I'm quite new to TypeScript (I work mostly with C#) so I created a little unit test using Jest to check whether `Map<TKey, TValue>` does what I want, specifically whether I can use the `forEach` method to iterate through each of the key-value pairs.

```
function createMap(): Map<number, string> {
    const map = new Map<number, string>();
    map.set(1, 'foo');
    map.set(2, 'bar');
    console.log(map); // Console output: Map(2) { 1 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar' }
    return map;
}

function iterateUsingForEach(map: Map<number, string>): number {
    let counter = 0;
    map.forEach((value: string, key: number, map: Map<number, string>) => {
        // Normally I'd do something more exciting here than just count the
        // elements, but in the interests of simplicity...
        counter++;
    });
    return counter;
}

describe('A Map instantiated using its constructor', () => {
    it('can be iterated using map.forEach()', () => {
        const map = createMap();
        const count = iterateUsingForEach(map);
        expect(count).toBe(2); // pass
    });
});
```

So far so good, the test passes, and I have a list of key-value pairs and can iterate over each of them, which is what I want. But the data to populate this object comes from a call to a web API, which returns a JSON document, which I need to deserialize to a `Map<number, string>`, so I added some more tests to simulate this use case:

```
function deserializeMap(): Map<number, string> {
    const json = '{ "1": "foo", "2": "bar" }';
    const map: Map<number, string> = JSON.parse(json) /*as Map<number, string>*/;
    console.log(map); // Console output: { '1': 'foo', '2': 'bar' }
    return map;
}

function iterateUsingObjectDotEntries(map: Map<number, string>): number {
    let count = 0;
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(map)) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

describe('A Map instantiated using deserialization', () => {
    it('can be iterated using map.forEach()', () => {
        const map = deserializeMap();
        const count = iterateUsingForEach(map); // fail - TypeError: map.forEach is not a function
        expect(count).toBe(2);
    });

    it('can be iterated using Object.entries(map)', () => {
        const map = deserializeMap();
        const count = iterateUsingObjectDotEntries(map);
        expect(count).toBe(2); // pass
    });
});
```

The first test fails because `map.forEach is not a function`, and looking at the console output, it seems that this time `map` isn't actually a `Map<number, string>` instance at all, but a plain object with properties called `1` and `2`, which probably has no prototype and therefore no methods, despite the fact that the `deserializeMap` function explicitly declares its return type as `Map<number, string>` and even tries to cast its return value to that type (I'm not sure whether that cast even has any effect - *edit* as per jcalz's comment I've commented that "cast" out as it's not actually a cast but a type assertion).

I'm guessing that the type checking performed by the TypeScript compiler isn't complaining about this because `map` is still [type compatible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) with `Map<number, string>` even though it's not actually an instance of that type?

The second test passes because it's not treating the `map` object as a list of key-value pairs, instead it's iterating through each of the property names and values. Functionally, using `Object.entries(map)` does what I want, but it strikes me as being analogous to using .net's `Reflection` to discover the names and values of the properties of an object at runtime, so I was wondering whether this would have an impact on performance. So I added this benchmark to compare the performance of the two approaches:

```
// Requires the tinybench package, to install it run:
// npm install tinybench --save-dev
// Also requires the following import:
// import { Bench } from 'tinybench';
it('runs a benchmark to compare the performance of the two approaches', async () => {
    const bench = new Bench({ iterations: 10000 });
    const instantiated = createMap();
    const deserialized = deserializeMap();

    bench
        .add('map.forEach()', () => {
            iterateUsingForEach(instantiated);
        })
        .add('Object.entries(map)', () => {
            iterateUsingObjectDotEntries(deserialized);
        });

    await bench.run();
    console.table(bench.table());
});
```

I've run this quite a few times and the results vary, but `Object.entries(map)` seems to take between 1.5 and 2 times as long as `map.forEach()` to do the same job. Example output:

```
    ┌─────────┬───────────────────────┬─────────────┬───────────────────┬──────────┬─────────┐
    │ (index) │       Task Name       │   ops/sec   │ Average Time (ns) │  Margin  │ Samples │
    ├─────────┼───────────────────────┼─────────────┼───────────────────┼──────────┼─────────┤
    │    0    │    'map.forEach()'    │ '1,739,642' │ 574.8305975247757 │ '±8.27%' │ 869822  │
    │    1    │ 'Object.entries(map)' │ '1,074,330' │ 930.8122055151725 │ '±1.02%' │ 537167  │
    └─────────┴───────────────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────────┴──────────┴─────────┘
```

So my question is, can I deserialize the JSON document to an actual instance of `Map<number, string>`, complete with its prototype and methods, rather than an object which is just type compatible with that type, in order to take advantage of the faster performance of `map.forEach()`?

Edit: I don't think this is a duplicate of [cast data received from backend to a frontend interface in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77287542/16563198) because that seems to be about mapping the properties of an object with one shape to the properties of a different object with a different shape, whereas I'm trying to create an object from JSON which has a prototype and methods.

Comment: Any POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object) is not a Map.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz I've removed the type assertion, clearly I'd misunderstood what the `as` keyword is for.

Comment: `JSON.parse()` will not produce `Map`s unless you pass in something like your `iterate...` function as a second argument. Thus the only way you can affect performance is to implement that function better (maybe just `for (let k in obj) {...}` will probably be faster).  This has little to do with TypeScript per se; it's just JavaScript. You might want to add tags about JavaScript and performance if you're looking for the best performance here, otherwise the answer is just "there's no built-in way to do this, you have to implement it".  How should we proceed here?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to reproduce the way .net libraries like [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) deserialize JSON documents to an actual instance of the requested type, rather than some object which is sort of the same shape, something which I thought the type checking in TypeScript would make easier. It's not a purely performance question, more an attempt to avoid getting into a habit of writing code which performs badly. I'll have a think about how to edit the question to clarify this, and I'll do some searches about reviver and other ways to iterate over objects.

Comment: TypeScript has essentially no runtime effect; it just tries to make it easier to write JavaScript.  So JavaScript is what you're asking about here, and TypeScript is sort of a red herring (no matter what types you annotate or assert, the runtime behavior will be unaffected).  There is no built-in functionality to serialize/deserialize `Map`s to/from JSON.  You can customize behavior by passing callbacks to `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`, *or* you can just use the default behavior and then deal with the results yourself.  [There's really no difference](https://tsplay.dev/N7QGRW).

Comment: I'd be happy to write any of this up as an answer if you want.  Or maybe you want to [edit] the question first.  Anyway, I'll check back later.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cast data received from backend to a frontend interface in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287542/cast-data-received-from-backend-to-a-frontend-interface-in-typescript)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and links. I'll need a good 24 hours to digest them and experiment further. It does sound like this is heading towards a conclusion of "TypeScript isn't .net, you can't expect them to behave the same way" and "you need to implement this behaviour yourself", which I guess is a step on the way to me learning TypeScript.

Comment: JSON *"is an open standard file format and data interchange format"*  ->  Full Stop.  It is not about serializing JS objects as in C#.  Unfortunate that we use the term "serialize" in JSON context, but it's just a string.