# Can typescript convert between objects without losing type annotations?

Tags: typescript

sorry, my English is poor but I will try my best to describe my confusion.

I want to implement a function in TypeScript that can replace the keys of the Object.

for example:

```
interface Target {
    name: string;
    ID: number;
}

// the function
function objectAdapter<T extneds Object, K extends keyof T>(
    data: T,
    transformMap: Record<keyof Target, K>
) {
    return Object.keys(transformMap).reduce((p, c) => (p[c] = data[transformMap[c]], p), {})
}

const result = objectAdapter({ nickname: 'link', id: 123456 }, { name: 'nickname', id: 'ID' });
```

The code above can achieve my goal like:

```
// transform data from
{
    nickname: 'link',
    id: 123456
}
// to
{
    name: 'link',
    ID: 123456
}
```

But when I fill the value of transformMap, IDE was not give a selectable tip correctly.
[image]

In addition, all prop of result will be infered as 'string|number', but what I need is like interface Target.

Thanks for reading and waiting for apply.Thanks♪(･ω･)ﾉ.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cast data received from backend to a frontend interface in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287542/cast-data-received-from-backend-to-a-frontend-interface-in-typescript)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to create a mapped type to enforce the mapping types correctly and then use it in your `objectAdapter()` and specify your return type.

**Example**

```
interface Target {
    name: string;
    ID: number;
}

type KeyMapping<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: keyof Target;
};

function objectAdapter<T extends Record<string, any>, K extends KeyMapping<T>>(
    data: T,
    transformMap: K
): Target {
    return Object.keys(transformMap).reduce((p, c) => {
        p[transformMap[c]] = data[c];
        return p;
    }, {} as Target);
}

const result = objectAdapter({ nickname: 'link', id: 123456 }, { nickname: 'name', id: 'ID' });
```

Comment: I really apperciate your help! If I wanna make the `objectAdapter` function has wider applicability for converting objectA to objectB through replacing key without giving a specific interface(e.g. `Target`), can TypeScript support this?

Comment: Yes, you can make the `objectAdapter () ` more generic by using TS's mapped types and generics and this the function work with any target type.