# Create an object mapping function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to be able to map object keys to another object.

For example:

I have this object:

```js
{
  a: "aee",
  b: "bee",
  c: "cee"
}
```

I want to turn this object into this object:

```js
{
  XX: "aee",
  YY: "bee",
  ZZ: "cee"
}
```

Based on the following predefined map:

```
{
  a: "XX",
  b: "YY",
  C: "cee"
}
```

`createMapper` is a function that returns another function.

- it receives the map (object).
- it returns a function, which can be called with the object you want to get the transformation on.
- calling the returned function, will return a new object, the returned object is the final result (the mapped object).

Here's the code:

```js
const createMapper = (map) => (objectToMap) => {
  const result = {};
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(objectToMap)) {
    const mappedKey = map[key];
    if (mappedKey)
      result[mappedKey] = value;
  }
  return result;
};

const mapMySchema = createMapper({
  a: 'XX',
  b: 'YY',
  c: 'ZZ',
});

const body = mapMySchema({
  a: "aee",
  b: "bee"
});

console.log(body)
// {
//   "XX": "aee",
//   "YY": "bee"
// }
```

It's working exactly as intended. Now I want to type this function.

The rules are:

- `map` is an object with key value pairs as strings.
- `objectToMap` is an object, with *some* or *all* the keys from the keys of `map`, while the **value** could be *anything*.
- the result at the end, which is the returned mapped object will be of type object, where I want to have autocompletion.

Finally:

- I want to provide an optional method for the consumers of my generic function to be                                                                             able to specify not only the keys of the of `objectToMap`, but also the values' types. This will be done when the consumer of my function provides a generic argument to the `mapMySchema` function.

So here's what I did:

```
export const createMapper =
  <AK extends string, DK extends string>(map: Record<AK, DK>) =>
  <GAK extends keyof AK, GV>(objectToMap: Record<GAK, GV>): Record<any, GV> => {
    const result: Record<any, GV> = {}
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(objectToMap)) {
      const mappedKey = map[key as AK]
      if (mappedKey) result[mappedKey] = value as GV
    }
    return result
  }

const mapMySchema = createMapper({
  a: 'XX',
  b: 'YY',
  c: 'ZZ',
})

const body = mapMySchema({
  a: 'aee',
  b: 'bee',
})
```

However, the typing of my function is wrong. Firstly, I am getting a red highlighter under `a`:

[image]

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a' does not exist in type 'Record<number | unique symbol | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | ... 35 more ... | "at", string>'.ts(2353)
```

Secondly, I don't see autocompletion when I write:

```
body. // < no auto completion!
```

Comment: You have unnecessary `keyof` - `<GAK extends keyof AK, GV>`. Without it there are no errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cast data received from backend to a frontend interface in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287542/cast-data-received-from-backend-to-a-frontend-interface-in-typescript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<AK extends string, DK extends string>(map: Record<AK, DK>)
```

This won't work because you lose the mapping between keys and values. This means that if you have a mapping object of:

```
{ a: 'x', b: 'y' }
```

You end up with:

```
{ [K in 'a' | 'b']: 'x' | 'y' }
```

And now the type can no longer track that `'a'` maps to `'x'` and `'b'` maps to `'y'`.

You also have a return type of `Record<any, GV>` which is of no help since the keys are literally `any`.

So we need a better input generic type, and a better output generic type.

---

To fix it you need be generic over the whole object type, for both the key map and the data, not just their keys and values.

```
export function createMapper<
  const TKeyMap extends Record<string, string>,
>
```

Now you can get the keys via `keyof TKeyMap` or the values via `TKeyMap[keyof TKeyMap]`. Or, more importantly, map the type with:

```
{ [K in keyof TKeyMap]: TKeyMap[K] } // identical to `TKeyMap`
```

This mapped type preserves which keys map to which values. This is very important.

Lastly here, the `const` prefix for the generic type tells Typescript to infer literal types instead of just something like `string`. This will infer `TKeyMap` as `{ a: 'x', b: 'y' }` instead of `{ a: string, b: string }`. But you could also throw `as const` after the object you pass in, like this:

```
createMapper({ ... } as const)
```

---

The inner function parameters and generics can now be typed more simply:

```
  return <
    TData extends Partial<
      Record<keyof TKeyMap, unknown>
    >
  >(
    objectToMap: TData
  ): // TODO: return type here
```

This says that the `objectToMap` parameter must have a subset of the same keys as `TKeyMap`, each of which have an `unknown` value type. `TData` will capture whatever that is and we can pass it through.

---

The inner function return type is where is gets fun. That looks like this:

```
  {
    [ K in keyof TData as K extends keyof TKeyMap
      ? TKeyMap[K]
      : never
    ]: TData[K]
  }
```

This is where that mapped typed comes in.

It maps over the keys of `TData` and renames them according to `TKeyMap` with the `as`.

But we need to make sure that `K` is actually in the `TKeyMap` first, since `TData` might be a subtype of the constraint that has extra keys. If the key is in there, then look up what map it to as the new key name. If it's not there the key resolves to `never` and the key is omitted from the result.

For the values, just use whatever value types are on `TData` at eacy key `K` with `TData[K]`.

---

For the function body, save yourself some headache with:

```
const result = {} as any
```

Then do your implementation. I almost *never* recommend using `any` but in highly generic cases like this where a simple function has complex input/output types, it's going to be really hard to get typescript to allow what you are trying to do.

So cover this function with some tests and tell Typescript you know what you are doing.

---

Putting all that together might look like:

```
export function createMapper<
  const TKeyMap extends Record<string, string>,
>(map: TKeyMap) {
  return <
    TData extends Partial<
      Record<keyof TKeyMap, unknown>
    >
  >(
    objectToMap: TData
  ): {
    [ K in keyof TData as K extends keyof TKeyMap
      ? TKeyMap[K]
      : never
    ]: TData[K]
  } => {
    // Typescript's going to have a hard time here. So I would
    // type this as any, do the things you need to do and cover
    // this with some tests.
    const result = {} as any 
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(objectToMap)) {
      const mappedKey = map[key]
      if (mappedKey) result[mappedKey] = value
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

Which works like you expect:

```
const mapMySchema = createMapper({
  a: 'XX',
  b: 'YY',
  c: 'ZZ',
})

const body = mapMySchema({
  a: 'aee',
  b: 123,
})
// type:  { XX: string, YY: number }
// value: { XX: 'aee', YY: 123 }
```

---

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzVYAQxmAFlCwxgoAeAKDjxwGd4AVAaWAE9yw5QJFABNmcAErA00YTVZRMKAOYAaOPMVKAfCrpaAFAFsKALjicefAJRwA3gzgEYSKLnqNGbACLFCAkEKicAAKhLCYhAA27h6MktJQsgDWPBAI5ly8FGqoSSgQAO4oWg6MJWX6pXAQAEYAVlIwbBB8Zt6+DlZm9rEA2nAccIpwKdxp5j4wfoRig4LAImKj4xZZYFWMAPwZlhS9HAC6G3BmKMAAbtRVB22ThPtHjAC+cAC8WnZVAPRf5txUzHwmDAMAA5GIlBBNHAYBA4AALQiXOB+RGJGGYQzABHUYAAOjgAGU4QBJOAFCBISLCb6-GD-bEweGYMQzFEobhqYRwpmM5nKMRjJBwM7AYQwuHc9ni6SXKC0mHMsQFTBM9QQLEw4CsZh4qrSFCsRzaqnwV52F5swgcuBVBDQOD6A1G3qjNTnKJIYAHarpADy9UaeIWMAU2v0tQaGGa1hsPViTEN8GMlDFmTecBTrp4jwTmHSRgoVGEmRsBGYpt6KeLmR95o9kS9VSeVScLlw5dNDhbLbozuTFFI3EJaHhwGMGfwRBIfCoUH08cIZlBAA0V6DdIwasuAJo7jcONDLgBax4PTysdD7LHgNQgwm4GZTQ5HY+MC4cS7goMIwGAB63MwAEYACYAGZdAvK9nQgSJ8UiCAlH0O8H0vH4EwTAA9TYgA)